# How to change ubercart's login text

Tags: text, authentication, ubercart

When a user is redirected to the login screen after clicking the checkout button (because they are an anonymous user), I want to change the login message that reads,"You must login before you can proceed to checkout" to something more meaningful. I have Googled this and searched this site and not found how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message is set in the `uc_cart_checkout` method in `ubercart/uc_cart/uc_cart.pages.inc`

See this post on how to override messages as set by `drupal_set_message` -  [Alter messages in Drupal 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942785/alter-messages-in-drupal-7)